# Reuse items from array with forloop

Tags: templating, loop, array

I have a loop of a list of regions on a project, this could be an infinite list of areas as my client's customer-base grows.

The project branding has four key colours, I have these in an array:

```
{% set themes = [
    'yellow',
    'red',
    'teal',
    'blue'
] %}
```

What I'm looking to do is grab one of these themes as I loop over my regions with a basic `{% for region in regions %}`, then on the 5th, 9th and so on loop jump back to #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to have it just assign them one after the other? If so, then you can just use [Twig’s `cycle` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html).

```
{% set themes = [
    'yellow',
    'red',
    'teal',
    'blue'
] %}

{% for region in regions %}
 <a href="{{ region.url }}" class="text-{{ cycle(themes, loop.index) }}">{{ region.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked: `{{ cycle(themes, loop.index) }}`. Thanks, mate!

Comment: Ah, good catch! That’ll teach me to write from my meatbrain and not refer to the docs. I’ve updated the response accordingly, including documentation.

Comment: Another update, the array starts at 0 whilst the loop started at 1... so `loop.index - 1` was needed to start from the start. ‍♂️

Comment: Ah, true. You don’t need to use math, though. You can just use `loop.index0` instead!